# Return value with FancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I wonder if it was possible to have a return value with FancyBox?
I want to launch a window with several AJAX FancyBox choice, once made ​​his choice, is it possible to return its value to the main window?

If you have an idea,
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your explanation of the issue isn't clear at all. What is it that you want to achieve, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fancybox has the ability to make event listener before and after window close.

```
$("#myFancy").fancybox({
  onCleanup: function() {
    alert($("#IDinsideTheFancybox").val());
  },
  onClosed: function() {
    alert("Closed!");
  }
});
```

Just pass the data in an event.

More info here: http://fancybox.net/home . Examples show how to use event listeners.

Comment: Thanks !
I use the new version of facybox : http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs
So it's not the same method, but in the tab "Callbacks" you can find all of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having multiple Fancyboxes with the choices, why not have one which contains different buttons or links to each different option. You can then do what you need on the click of these elements, rather than trying to get a value from the FancyBox itself (which I'm pretty sure isn't a standard feature).